# Captured photo orientation is not correct with custom camera implementation on few device(s) in Android

Tags: android-camera, surfaceview, screen-orientation, android-bitmap

I have implemented custom camera to take the pictures. On few devices, Picture is not being shown as in the orientation it is taken. Its rotating 180 degrees on Samsung T350 8-inch Tablet. But its working as expected on all other devices that I have tested.

```
public int setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity, int mCameraId, Camera mCamera, boolean portrait) {

    android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
    android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(mCameraId, info);
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    int degrees = 0;

    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
    }

    int result;
    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {

        result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
    } else {  // back-facing
        result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
    return result;
}
```

Here is Callback:

```
private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        try {

            m_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);             

                  if (getScreenOrientation() == 1){
                    mBitmap = BitmapHelper.getRotatedBitmap(m_bitmap, 270);
                    }
                }else if (getScreenOrientation() == 0){
                 mBitmap = BitmapHelper.getRotatedBitmap(m_bitmap,0);
                }else if (getScreenOrientation() == 9){
                       mBitmap =BitmapHelper.getRotatedBitmap(m_bitmap, 90);
                 }else if (getScreenOrientation() == 8){
                   mBitmap = BitmapHelper.getRotatedBitmap(m_bitmap,180);
                }
            }

            mImageViewPreview.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stopCameraPreview();
    }
};


// getting screenOrientation
private int getScreenOrientation() {
    int rotation = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;
    int orientation;
     // if the device's natural orientation is portrait:
    if ((rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0
            || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180) && height > width ||
            (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90
                    || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270) && width > height) {
         isLandScape = false;
        switch(rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE;
                break;
            default:
                Log.e("", "Unknown screen orientation. Defaulting to " + "portrait.");
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
                break;
        }
      }
    // if the device's natural orientation is landscape or if the device
    // is square:
    else {
         isLandScape = true;
        switch(rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                orientation =
                        ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                orientation =
                        ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT;
                break;
            default:
                Log.e("", "Unknown screen orientation. Defaulting to " +
                        "landscape.");
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
                break;
        }
     }
    return orientation;
}
```

Please help me out.